# UI-Router for item list Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I'm facing some problems with my simple code (study), i really need some help to fix this.

First of all i have a php file who provides a json.

app.php

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=caio', 'root', '');

    $a = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM usuario");
    $b = json_encode($a->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    echo $b;
    ?>
```

It's a simple json with id, name and surname

Also i have a Js file to get this.
app.js

```
var meuApp = angular.module('meuApp', ['ui.router']);

meuApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$stateProvider
    .state('usuarios.detail', {

        url: "/usuarios/{id}",
        templateUrl: 'uDetail.html'

    });
    });



    meuApp.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('app.php')
    .success(function(data) {
         $scope.usuarios = data;
         console.log(data);

         //just checking in the console...
          var id = data[0].id
          console.log(id);
          var nome = data[0].nome
          console.log(nome);
    });


   }]);
```

and finally my html file

```
<html ng-app="meuApp" lang="pt">

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="userCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
            <a ui-sref="usuarios.detail">{{usuario.nome}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

If i want to show, ok the code is working, but i want to click in each name and then the template shows me the id, name and surname of this "person". That's my problem.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some minor changes in order to get your code working, check the files bellow:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="userCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        <a ui-sref="users.detail({id: user.id, user: user})">{{user.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div ui-view></div>

</body>
```

**app.js**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('users', {
    abstract: true,
    url: 'users',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
  })

  .state('users.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'users.detail.html',
    params: {
      user: null
    },
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.user = $stateParams.user;
    }
  });

});

app.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {

 // replace this with your service call
    $scope.users = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'john',
      surname: 'doe'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'mary',
      surname: 'poppins'
    }];

  }
]);
```

**user.detail.html**

```html
<fieldset>

<div>
    <label>id: </label> {{user.id}}
</div>

<div>
    <label>name: </label> {{user.name}}
</div>

<div>
    <label>surname: </label> {{user.surname}}
</div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Working perfectly with my back-end, Thank you Romulo

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to pass person object from one state to another state.

For that you can use `params` attribute of `ui-router`. When you click any perticular person at that time you need to pass id also while routing from one state to another because you already configure in url `"/usuarios/{id}"`.
ui-router will match that property from params and will set in url.

Now you can successfully pass clicked object from one state to another. Get that object with `$stateParams` service of ui-router in controller of `usuarios.detail` state so that you can display in `uDetail.html`

```
meuApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$stateParams){

    $stateProvider
        .state('usuarios.detail', {
            url: "/usuarios/{id}",
            params: {
              id: null,
              person:null
            },
            templateUrl: 'uDetail.html',
            controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
              $scope.portfolioId = $stateParams.id;
              $scope.person = $stateParams.person; 
              console.log("State parameters " + JSON.stringify($stateParams));
            }

        });
});
```

and in your template where you are showing the list.

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
            <a ui-sref="usuarios.detail({ id:usuario.id,person:usuario})">{{usuario.nome}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

See above code which I gave for your reference.

You can see this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/iK9y4th6XLSk0s5jvx6C?p=preview) for in detail idea of ui-router.